# How to control and modify the std::map ordering using a user-defined key

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, stdmap, user-defined-types

I started out by using a `std::string` as my map key, as each item in my map can be uniquely identified by a string alone.

Then I realised that it would be a lot more useful to me to have the map ordered in a certain way, based on another parameter, so I added an `int` called priority to my key to help with ordering. The idea is that I iterate over the map and process the higher priority items first. I now have the following user-defined `struct` as my map key :

```
struct MyKey {

    // key data
    std::string addr;
    int priority;

    // constructor
    MyKey(const std::string & s, const int p) 
        : addr(s), priority(p) {}

    // overloaded operator
    bool operator<(const MyKey &that) const {

        // same key if addr is the same
        if (that->addr == this.addr)
            return false;

        // not same key so look at priorities to determine order
        if (that.priority < this->priority)
            return true;
        if (that.priority > this->priority)
            return false;

        // priorities are the same so use the string compare
        return (that.addr > this->addr);
    }
};
```

The map ordering appears to be working correctly, and when new items are added they are entered at the expected position automatically if you were to iterate over the map. For instance for a map of `std::string` values:

```
std::map<myKey, std::string> myMap;

myKey key1 = myKey(std::string("key1"), 1);
myKey key2 = myKey(std::string("key2"), 2);
myKey key3 = myKey(std::string("key3"), 3);
myKey key4 = myKey(std::string("key4"), 4);

myMap[key1] = std::string("value1");
myMap[key2] = std::string("value2");
myMap[key3] = std::string("value3");
myMap[key4] = std::string("value4");
```

Would result in the following map key-value pairs at respective indexes:

```
[0] { addr = "key4", priority = 4 }, { "value4" }
[1] { addr = "key3", priority = 3 }, { "value3" }
[2] { addr = "key2", priority = 2 }, { "value2" }
[3] { addr = "key1", priority = 1 }, { "value1" }
```

However...I am having problems when it comes to modifying an existing priority of a key that is already present in the map.

In this situation, `find()` and `[]` (with respect to `std::map`) don't work as I want them to:

```
myKey modified_key1 = myKey(std::string("key1"), 5);

// problem 1 - this does not return iterator to "key1", 
// but instead to end of the map
auto & foundKey = myMap.find(modified_key1);

// problem 2 - this adds a brand new item to the map
myMap[modified_key1] = std::string("value1");
```

After `problem 2` as mentioned above, I am getting a new item added to the map with the same `addr` of an existing item. The new item appears to be added in the expected position based on the new (modified) `priority`, but the existing item to be updated remains as it was. So I end up with 2 items in the map with the same `addr` in their keys:

```
[0] { addr = "key1", priority = 5 }, { "value1" }
[1] { addr = "key4", priority = 4 }, { "value4" }
[2] { addr = "key3", priority = 3 }, { "value3" }
[3] { addr = "key2", priority = 2 }, { "value2" }
[4] { addr = "key1", priority = 1 }, { "value1" }
```

This is a problem for me as I would like to still rely on the notion that the `addr` of the map item key is unique.

What I want is the map to realise it already has an item with the same key (or more to the point the same key `addr`) and to re-order the item accordingly.

I have tried experimenting with compare functors as part of the map definition, and also overloading the keys `==` operator, but the same problem persists.

What am I missing or should I be approaching this differently?

Comment: you cant modify keys. the value_type of a map is `std::pair<const KEY,VALUE>`. you can erase the element and insert it with the updated key

Comment: Hi jwide87, if you wanted to increase your chances to have a useful and complete answer, you should definitely provide a [mcve].

Comment: if you only want to modify the `addr` and not the `priority` and you only use `priority` for sorting, then you might want to consider to put the `addr` in the value instead of the key

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I can sort of see why `[]` is not going to work now, but still unclear on why `find()` would not work in my case. From the literature std::map::find "Two keys are considered equivalent if the container's comparison object returns false reflexively (i.e., no matter the order in which the elements are passed as arguments)." Which I think my overloaded operator handles?

Comment: add a overload for == operator also .. then you will see the find returning what you want .. !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your comparison operator implemented incorrectly, it does not provide [strict weak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering) ordering hence undefined behavior of the `std::map`, lets say you have 3 objects of `MyKey`:

```
MyKey mk1{ "a",3 }, mk2{ "b", 2 }, mk3 { "a", 1 };
mk1 < mk2 -> true as 3 > 2
mk2 < mk3 -> true as 2 > 1
mk1 < mk3 -> false as addr is the same, but must be true
```

[live example](https://ideone.com/21ZjJK)

I do not think your problem is easily solvable with `std::map`. Possible solution is to use [`boost::multi_index`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) with address as one index and priority as another. To change priority of existing element `boost::multi_index` provides method to replace data.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `MyKey` you can use `std::tuple<int, std::string>`, it defines the relational operators for you:

```
using MyKey = std::tuple<int, std::string>;
```

Saves you a dozen of lines.

---

You cannot modify keys of elements in any associative containers. Instead, you need to remove the element using the old key and re-insert it with a new key.

Comment: `std::tuple` would not work here as intended as OP has special comparison operator, which is different that one provided by tuple. Also this answer does not really address issue asked.

Comment: @Slava I assumed that the original comparison was not implemented correctly.

Comment: Then sorting would not work they way OP wants and that is the whole point of the question. OP wants to have only one key with the same address in the map. You did not really look into question and also downvoted my answer just for revenge, nice.